# Angular Array Separate into new array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array like this:

Model:

```
export class Total {
    Id: number;
    Products: string;
    LastUpdated: Date;
}
```

I have a list of this with:

```
myList[] = this.service.getProducts().toPromise();
```

How do I make a new array with only get Products and LastUpdated from myList?

```
myProducts[] = ["prod1","prod2","prod3","prod3"];
myDates[] = ["2020-03-01","2020-03-02","2020-03-05","2020-03-06"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that here `this.service.getProducts().toPromise();` gives you type `Promise<Total[]>` (not an array) so you would write `myList` instead of `myList[]`.
This way, for products and dates its better/saftier to keep them like `Promise<string[]>` type.

```
const myProducts = this.myList.then(list => list.map(item => item.Products));
const myDates = this.myList.then(list => list.map(item => item.LastUpdated));
```

If you are sure that you need `string[]` type, you can wait for this promise:

```
this.myList.then(list => {
    this.myProducts = list.map(item => item.Products);
    this.myDates = list.map(item => item.LastUpdated);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. Try the following

```js
const myProducts = this.myList.map(item => item.Products);
const myDates = this.myList.map(item => item.LastUpdated);
```

Comment: you can use reduce so you will only iterate through the array once...

```const [myProcucts, myDates] = this.myList.reduce((total, item) => {
      total.push([item.Products, item.LastUpdates])
      return total
}, [] as Array<string[], Date[]>);```

Comment: @AlexandreDias, ofc you can use reduce, but not that way you did. It gives an unexpected result.

Answer (score 0):

Using `map`you could achieve the result, but you would need to iterate through the entire array twice, which might be bad on large arrays...

So you can use `reduce` instead.

```
const [myProcucts, myDates]: [string[], Date[]] = this.myList.reduce((total: [string[], Date[]], item: Total) => {
        // push product value to the array of Products
        total[0].push(item.Products);

        // push lastUpdated value to the array of lastUpdated
        total[1].push(item.LastUpdated);
        return total
    }, [[],[]]);
```